# How can I remove <style> tags using DOM?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that contains HTML text from a web page. The text includes a style area like this but with different contents inside.

```
var myHtml = "xxxxx
   <style type="text/css"> 
   .... css style definition area.
   yyyy"
   </style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way via the DOM;

```
var el = document.createElement("DIV");
el.innerHTML = html_string;

var style = el.getElementsByTagName("STYLE");
for (var i = style.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    style[i].parentNode.removeChild(style[i]);
}

alert(el.innerHTML);
```

Comment: jQuery way: `$('<div>').append(myHtml).remove('style').html()`